# Can PixelSearch return multiple coords with the same color?

Tags: autohotkey

The function [PixelSearch](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm) returns the first pixel that matches a specific color. Thing is that I would need to find more pixels with the same color but in different coords.

For example if I have a red pixel in `420x689` and also in `864x1022`, PixelSearch only returns the first coord. How can I also recognize the second red pixel coord?

The code I have is: `PixelSearch, Sx, Sy, 380, 80, 1550, 900, 0xFFA004, 1, Fast RGB` but only returns 1 pixel. Is there any other function/approach I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

took a while but i have had this problem in the past and worked it out first it scans the main area and if it finds a pixel then it searches after that pixel for the rest of the line if it finds it searches past that pixel to the end of the line then once it gets to the end of the line does a search for everything in the area under the scanned line and repeats tested and working. this is going to be useful for many scripts i have wanted this for a while. it can be slow on big areas but that's probably the fastest you can get.

```
CoordMode, mouse, Screen
multipixelsearch(colour, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
varx1 := x1
vary1 := y1
varx2 := x2
vary2 := y2
loop
{
PixelSearch, x, y, varx1, vary1, varx2, vary2, colour, 0, RGB Fast
if (ErrorLevel) {
    return
}
yfound := y
forcoord(x, y)
loop {
PixelSearch, x, y, x, y, x2, y, colour, 0, RGB Fast
if (ErrorLevel) {
    vary1 := yfound + 1
    Break
} else {
x := x+1
forcoord(x, y)
}
}
}
}
forcoord(x, y) {
;what it does for every coord goes here
}
return
Esc::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works, although it is likely not the best/ most efficient solution to this problem.

You could try and iterate across your given range of pixels and add pixels that match the specified color to an array.

Here is what I got:

```
#SingleInstance Force

xStorage:=[]
yStorage:=[]

startX:=380
startY:=80
endX:=1550
endY:=900
TargetColor:=0xFFA004

iterX:=startX
iterY:=startY

while(iterX<=endX)
{
    while(iterY<=endY)
    {
        PixelGetColor, currentColor, %iterX%, %iterY%
        
        if(currentColor==TargetColor){
            
            xStorage.Push(iterX)
            yStorage.Push(iterY)
            ;MsgBox %iterX% %iterY% %currentColor%
            
        }
        
        
        iterY++
    }
    
    iterY=0
    iterX++
}

for index, element in xStorage
{
    MsgBox % "Element number " . index . " of the X-cood is " . element
    
}
for index, element in yStorage
{
    MsgBox % "Element number " . index . " of the Y-cood is " . element
    
}


esc::ExitApp
```

Edit: fixed bad code that stopped the y iterable from reseting after each line/cycle.

Comment: This indeed does seem super super inefficient, haha. Also, there seems to be some problem with the loop logic. I could swear it's only going to check the pixels that are on `x = 380`. For a more efficient approach, maybe first `PixelSearch` the inner region, and then the outer region in how ever many parts it's going to need. [Example](https://i.imgur.com/qjZGYgp.png): Red would be the inner region and rest of the colors the outer region. So first search in the red region and then in all the other colored regions in order. (Just be sure to not search the same region twice)

Comment: @0x464e ty for pointing out the Logic error in my while loop, it looks like I forgot to reset the Y-axis iterable after each line/ cycle